# How do I find the probability that one of my probabilities will occur?

Tags: python, statistics

I've been struggling with this problem all day. I've got a set of events each with probabilities.

```
{'Bob': 0.82,
 'Derek': 0.69,
 'Sarah': 0.91,
 'Peter': 0.46,
 'Amy': 0.62,
 'Ryan': 0.7}
```

I created a list of outcomes that are not conditional. For example P(Derek) and P(Amy), which is the intersection, so I multiply.

```
P(Derek ∩ Amy) = .82 *.62 = 0.42779999999999996
```

Here is my full list of outcomes I'm interested in:

```
{('Derek', 'Amy'): 0.42779999999999996,
 ('Bob', 'Peter', 'Amy'): 0.233864,
 ('Bob', 'Ryan', 'Sarah'): 0.52234,
('Bob', 'Ryan', 'Amy'): 0.35588,
...
('Ryan', 'Sarah', 'Derek'): 0.43953}
```

None of my outcomes are duplicates nor are they supersets.I want to find the probability that exactly one of these occurs.

Is this the correct method?

```
prob = 1.0

for event in events:
    prob *= (1.0 - event)

probability_of_one_event = 1 - prob
print("Probability of at one event is", probability_of_one_event)
```

I'm asking because the number I'm getting is 99%, which seems too high. I need help thinking about this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a little more background?  Your data has a pair of names and then the rest contain three names.  What are the first probabilities that you list.  They can't be the proportion of a population because they do not add up to 1 so what are they?

Comment: They're potential outcomes. Imagine a game where there can be multiple winners. But not every combination is valid for a "win".

Comment: Your method would work if all the events in your event set were independent. But they aren't. For example imagine 2 coins A and B and the event set {A = tail, B= tail, A = B = tail} with the odds (0.5, 0.5, 0.25); your method would give the probability 1- (1-0.5)(1-0.5)(1-0.25) =  0,8125 while the actual probability of your event set is 0.75 .

Comment: @Swifty, why would it be .75?

Comment: Because the contrary of "any in the event set" is "A != tail and B != tail", whose probablility is 0.25